# Maximum souvenirs possible with given conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

(I was not sure where to post this question whether here or in the CS one, but I felt it was rather math'y)
This was a problem from a local programming contest held at my school (I couldn't solve it and I am asking for a solution with detailed explanations please.)
***the problem states:***

You and a few friends went traveling to Russia, and you wanted some souvenirs. Luckily, you met the king of making souvenirs. He makes his unique souvenir "Lambda" using one of the following:
-2 eyes and a body
-2 eyes, a mouth and a body
-an eye, a mouth and a body
He isn't very good at math, so he asked you to tell him what is the maximum number of Lambdas he can make if he has $e$ eyes, $m$ mouths and $b$ bodies.

***Constraints:***
$0 \le e,m,b \le 10^8$

***Examples:***
$e = 1, m =2, b = 3$ Then $MAX = 1$
$e = 0, m =11, b = 2$ Then $MAX = 0$
$e = 14, m =21, b = 23$ Then $MAX = 14$
$e = 90, m =24, b = 89$ Then $MAX = 57$

(Thanks in Advance :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the second configuration is dominated by the other two, so ignore it.  Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the numbers of Lambdas of each of the remaining two types.  The problem is to maximize $x_1+x_2$ subject to
\begin{align}
2x_1 + 1x_2 &\le e &&(y_e \ge 0) \\
0x_1 + 1x_2 &\le m &&(y_m \ge 0) \\
1x_1 + 1x_2 &\le b &&(y_b \ge 0) \\
x_1, x_2 &\ge 0
\end{align}
The dual problem is to minimize $e y_e + m y_m + b y_b$ subject to
\begin{align}
2y_e + 0y_m +1y_b &\ge 1 &&(x_1 \ge 0) \\
1y_e + 1y_m +1y_b &\ge 1 &&(x_2 \ge 0) \\
y_e, y_m, y_b &\ge 0
\end{align}

Here are optimal solutions for your examples:
\begin{matrix}
e & m & b & x_1 & x_2 & y_e & y_m & y_b & \max =x_1 + x_2 = e y_e + m y_m + b y_b \\
\hline
1 &2 &3 &0 &1 &1 &0 &0   &1 \\
0 &11 &2 &0 &0 &1 &0 &0  &0 \\
14 &21 &23 &0 &14 &1 &0 &0 &14 \\
90 &24 &89 &33 &24 &1/2 &1/2 &0 & 57 \\
\end{matrix}
Because we have only two decision variable $x_1$ and $x_2$, it is reasonable to solve this linear programming problem by enumerating all extreme points.  By considering two constraints at a time, we find the following possibilities:
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 \\
\hline
(e-m)/2 & m \\
e-b & 2b-e \\
0 & e \\
e/2 & 0 \\
b-m & m \\
0 & m \\
0 & b \\
b & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
To maximize $x_1+x_2$ for given $e,m,b$, it suffices to compute this list of candidates, check feasibility for each one, and keep one that has the largest sum.

Comment: Excuse me. Can you please clarify what $y_e$, $y_m$ and $y_b$ are? and what are the numbers next to $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the inequalities above? (Thanks for the help)

Comment: The $y$ variables are linear programming dual multipliers.  The numbers next to $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the constraint coefficients.  For example, each unit of the first Lambda requires 2 eyes, and each unit of the third Lambda requires 1 eye, so the resource constraint for eyes is $2x_1+1x_2 \le e$.